# How do I write a list of strings to a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

Here's my code:

```
from random import random

f = open('Attractors1.txt', 'w')
for i in range(10):
    theta = (3.14/2)*random()
f.write(str(theta))
```

I'm trying to create a list of 10 theta values so I can call them in another program, but I don't think the objects are writing correctly. How do I know if I'm doing it write? Whenever I run the code and execute f.read() I get an error saying the file isn't open.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time trying to write to file, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing

Answer (score 3):

You can't `read` from a file opened in write-only mode.  :)

Since you're not writing within the loop, you'll only actually spit out a single number.  Even if you fixed that, you'd get a bunch of numbers all in one line, because you're not adding newlines.  `.write` isn't like `print`.

Also it's a good idea to use `with` when working with files, to ensure the file is closed when you think it should be.

So try this:

```
import math
from random import random

with open('Attractors1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        theta = (math.PI / 2) * random()
        f.write("{0}\n".format(theta))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('Attractors1.txt', 'w')
for i in range(10):
  theta = (3.14/2)*random()
f.write(str(theta))
f.close()
```

Then to read:

```
f = open('Attractors1.txt','r')
text = f.read()
print text
```

Edit: wups beaten to it

Comment: this doesn't fix the write-outside-loop problem